# nsis unable to copy file to system32

Tags: python-2.7, nsis

```
# define name of installer
OutFile "installer.exe"
SetOverwrite on
# define installation directory
InstallDir $DESKTOP

# For removing Start Menu shortcut in Windows 7
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Section
    ;StrCpy $INSTDIR "c:\Windows\System32\"
    SetOutPath $WINDIR\System32\
    ;MessageBox MB_OK $WINDIRSetOutPath $WINDIR\System32\
    MessageBox MB_OK $SYSDIR
    File "python27.dll"
SectionEnd
```

This is my script to copy python27.dll file to windows/system32
When i run this file it does nothing or am i doing something worng
thanks in advance new to nsis

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, try to inform the user about the prerequisites of your app and prompt him to install the python version suitable for your app. You can include the official python installer with your installer so the user can install it directly or you can launch it if the user checked to install it. Don't forget also to check if this version is already there or not, or if there is any other version that can run your app. Hope this help.
If you have to follow your method:
`Section "nameofsection" SetOutPath  $SYSDIR   File "python27.dll" SectionEnd`

Comment: OutFile "installer.exe"
SetOverwrite on
# define installation directory
InstallDir $DESKTOP
 
# For removing Start Menu shortcut in Windows 7
RequestExecutionLevel Admin
!include MUI2.nsh
!include UAC.nsh
# start default section
Section "nameofsection" 
 SetOutPath $SYSDIR 
 File "python27.dll" 
SectionEnd
It does nothing

Comment: How can i use official python install in my script if you can explain more
New to nsis

Comment: Is this 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit Windows there are [two system32 directories](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955767.aspx), one for 32-bit .DLLs and one for 64-bit .DLLs. 64-bit programs (including Explorer) see the real name of the 32-bit system32 directory; SysWOW64. The real system32 directory directory is hidden from 32-bit programs.

To always install to the "real"/native system32 folder you need to [disable the redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin
!include x64.nsh

Section
SetOutPath $SysDir

${If} ${RunningX64}
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
File "myfiles\64\file.dll" ; Install 64-bit file on 64-bit Windows
${EnableX64FSRedirection}

${Else}

File "myfiles\32\file.dll" ; Install 32-bit file on 32-bit Windows

${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

If your .DLL is always 32-bit then you don't have to do anything special:

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Section
SetOutPath $SysDir
File "myfiles\file.dll" ; Install 32-bit file
SectionEnd
```

Installing your files in system32 has been discouraged for nearly 20 years and you really should use `$COMMONFILES` or `$PROGRAMFILES\<company name>\Shared Files`.

Imagine what happens [if two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) different software vendors both decide that they need to install python27.dll in system32?! If you still insist on doing this then you should at least use [`Library.nsh`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixB.html#library) to install the file so `SharedDLLs` gets set correctly.